# socket.io emit all clients not emitting over SSL

Tags: socket.io

I have the normal socket.io set up:

Client:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io()
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected')
  socket.emit('message', 'I have connected')
})
socket.on('message', (msg) => console.log(msg))
```

Server:

```
import socket from 'socket.io'
const io = socket(/* httpsServer */)
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('new connection')
  socket.on('message', (msg) => console.log(msg))
  socket.emit('message', 'This works!')
  io.sockets.emit('message', `This doesn't!`)
})
```

For some reason emit to all works perfectly via http but not https. Via https the `io.sockets.emit` doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check the files, if you have files with http link instead of https, it will give you a mixed content error. You can't use both http and https files on your page if you are using SSL/HTTPS. Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

Comment: @Jer it's all SSL. It works when you emit to one socket, just not when you emit to all. Could it be a namespace issue?

Comment: are there any errors in your console? it can be a namespace issue but i'm not sure about that.

Comment: No errors. If I do `Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets)` after `socket:connection` on the server I get an empty array. However if I do a `setInterval` for a few seconds and then `socket.emit the client receives the message, so it's still connected and works. Is there any reason why the ref to the socket isn't stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the same socket server module isn't mounted to **both** `httpServer` and `httpsServer`.

I wrapped my socket server in a module and attached it first to the https server and then to the http server. This is why the single sockets would connect but then emit to all was trying to send out to the http sockets only.